# Exportar base MySQL com chaves estrangeiras

Tags: mysql

Minha hospedagem utiliza o phpMyAdmin, para gerenciar o banco e não permite a conexão remota por ser um plano grátis.

Preciso exportar minha base para a hospedagem, gerei o arquivo .sql com o comando `mysqldump -h host -u user -p base --routines > base.sql`, porém depois de colocar o arquivo .sql na hospedagem, todas as chaves estrangeiras foram perdidas.

Existe outra forma de fazer para que isso não ocorra?

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Basicamente você quer um comando que te dê o dump com as chaves estrangeiras junto?

Comment: Exatamente, eu acho que isso deve ser um problema na hospedagem, por ser um plano grátis, já que na minha máquina fiz um teste e as chaves vieram.

Comment: Acho muito difícil que seja algo que a hospedagem tenha feito de propósito, pois não faz sentido e eles teriam que forjar uma versão do MySQL com essa finalidade só para isso, o que não há motivo para se fazer. Entretanto, tenho um palpite melhor: As suas tabelas na hospedagem estão com MyISAM ou como InnoDB? Qual é a versão do MySQL de lá?

Comment: Na hospedagem esta MyISAM e versão 5.1, e na minha máquina InnoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyISAM não tem chaves estrangeiras e nem impõe integridade referencial. Isso significa que você não consegue puxar as chaves estrangeiras do seu banco de dados simplesmente porque elas nem sequer estão lá.

Comment: Caramba! Não sabia disso, vou procurar outra hospedagem. Obrigado pela ajuda Victor.